# Permission Denied message when I do an open xhhtprequest in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am writing a javascript routine that uses xhttprequest to access the ebay API. I am running the script on internet explorer. I was testing it on the ebay API sandbox and it was working ok. Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
var url = "https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/ws/api.dll";

var Req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");

Req.open("POST",url,false);
```

I stopped testing for a couple of weeks and then when I ran it again the script halted at the open command with the message 'Permission Denied'

I tried everything I could think of and searched the internet but couldn't find an answer.

Then I decided to try running the script against the live ebay server. I changed the url to https://api.ebay.com/ws/api.dll and the script worked.

Can anyone provide an explanation or suggest a reason for this. It is doing my head in

Thanks

Paul

Comment: You can't use XMLHttp to POST/GET to different domains. It's called the "same origin policy".

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355299/permission-denied-error-xmlhttprequest

Comment: *"I changed the url to `https://api.ebay.com/ws/api.dll` and the script worked."* Are you sure? How did you test this?

Comment: I thought it might be the problem of posting to different domains (same origin) but how does this explain the fact than I could run it against the test server for quite a long time before the shutters came down? an run this against the live server. If there was a safeguard I would have thought that

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know that's XSS and it's not allowed in any browser, unless things become archaic!
The reason why they don't allow that is because it would make stealing cookies, pwds, and anything merely a child's play.

So, you won't be able to use XHR from any page to another domain, UNLESS you have for example an addon (lets say in firefox) that drives all your requests for you, which is far fetched...

Comment: Is there some internet police program that investigates these issues and puts up the shutters. Is so I presume I will get the permission denied messge with the live server eventually. Also the script is on my server which I run using internet explorer on my PC. Isn't this what is called using a proxy server which is supposed to get round the different domains problem?different domains problem?

Comment: lol its your browser that doesn't let you do that and i guess you got it the wrong way, what a proxy does is read a web resource and pass it to the end user acting like a middle guy between you and the website. You cant achieve that on client side but what you would do is use AJAX to call a PHP script that resides on your own server and call the remote server from that script then return a response to your client: that works and is being done everywhere!
Here is an example in a diagram: http://tinyurl.com/phpajax
Consider the Database server to be ebay ...
I hope i didn't confuse you :)

Comment: But that's the thing - my browser is letting me do it - at least on the live server and for the moment. Thanks for putting me straight on the web proxy thing. I will give it a go.