# How to display certain JSON elements in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I would like to display the variable "hashrate" from [this](http://gaben.capyspool.co.uk/gabencoin/public/index.php?page=api&action=getpoolstatus&api_key=72f3fd60d9a536215a6f6f92938592a60f919586635d7d0dedcf6a394888c435) JSON file on a HTML webpage. I have looked around the internet, but many of the methods have not worked. Sorry if this is a duplicate question, I am very lost.

Comment: Could you include the code from what you tried?

Comment: have you tried something like `var parsed = JSON.parse(str)` and then `console.log(parsed)` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var json = {"getpoolstatus":{"version":"1.0.0","runtime":19.948959350586,"data":{"pool_name":"Capy's Pool - Gabencoin","hashrate":5.8254222222222,"efficiency":0,"workers":0,"currentnetworkblock":21903,"nextnetworkblock":21904,"lastblock":21903,"networkdiff":0.0392466,"esttime":28935.733248,"estshares":2572,"timesincelast":189,"nethashrate":451133}}};
```

your variable -    `json.getpoolstatus.data.hashrate`

Answer (score 0):

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); //Request the data
xhr.open('POST','http://gaben.capyspool.co.uk/gabencoin/public/index.php?page=api&action=getpoolstatus&api_key=72f3fd60d9a536215a6f6f92938592a60f919586635d7d0dedcf6a394888c435',true);
xhr.send();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4) { //When it's ready
        var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText); //Parse the data
        alert(data.getpoolstatus.data.hashrate); //And here it is!
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, may I have a line of HTML to show me how I would display this result?

Comment: `<div id="output"></div>` and `document.getElementById('output').textContent = data.getpoolstatus.data.hashrate`

Comment: Sorry, where would I put the 'document.getElementById('output').textContent = data.getpoolstatus.data.hashrate' part? I am extremely sorry for my lack of understanding and knowledge, I have only recently started using JavaScript.

Comment: You can put it where the `alert` is.

Comment: Here is my test HTML: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/WGcRGmiD) I am really sorry that I am getting you to spoon-feed this to me, in this case, ignorance certainly is not bliss. Once again, sorry for your trouble.

Comment: Almost. [Here it is](http://pastebin.com/FKufgTdr). And you should probably learn JS… https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn/javascript

Comment: Even though I am using your exact code, it is still not working. It loads for a while then shows me a blank page.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355299/permission-denied-error-xmlhttprequest/355303#355303

Comment: OK I have managed to get it working. However, the script only seems to work in the sub folder, 'gabencoin'. All the data for the pools' frontend is in this site. How would I be able to access the data from the root 'www' folder?

Comment: I think that deserves a full, [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).